Ubuntu recognizes different partitions and drives on disk 1 although Ubuntu recognizes it as a whole disk
I am trying to Install Ubuntu(24.04 LTS). While following this Tutorial. As in the video I created a unallocated Partition although going to Ubuntu. This is showing.

On Checking the terminal the terminal is telling that the whole disk 1 is being considered as one partition. How can I fix this?
Relevant Info:
RV -> 24.04 LTS
TU -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXxTxBPKecQ&t=221s
UE -> Ubuntu Desktop
Logs -> N/A

Your tutorials are using a different installer (ubiquity) to the system (Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop) you want to install (that will be installed using ubuntu-desktop-installer not ubiquity); so steps won't be identical; just similar. I don't understand your issue though, you mention a terminal but there was no picture or detail of what you actually did or saw there.

Do you have Windows partitions, with bitlocker, fast startup, hibernation or conversion to dynamic partitions? All those can prevent the Linux NTFS driver from seeing Windows. Post this above in question: sudo parted -l
